# C++ object dynamic naming

Tags: c++, oop, pointers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using unique dynamic variable names (not variable values!)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3441866/using-unique-dynamic-variable-names-not-variable-values)

I am new to object oriented programming with c++. I am trying to write an algebra solver using classes and objects.

For example, I would like to create a class named `term`.
I have a variable for example:

```
int number_of_term = 1;
```

Then I would like to create an term object with the name `number_of_term`.

I tried to do it with a pointer, but it didn't work:

```
term *number_of_term;
```

Is it possible in C++ to create and name an object dynamically? Can I use a variable as the name of an object?

If it's not, what should I do to make something similar.

Comment: @Joe not exactly the same, but this has to be a duplicate of something

Comment: You are trying to use objects like a C character array. Don't do that. use a std::vector, std::list, or std::deque

Answer (score 3):

No, the name of an object in C++ must be determined at compile-time. C++ is not a dynamic language. You should probably use `std::map` or `std::unordered_map` instead. These will let you map a string to an object. This is how dynamic languages that let you determine the name of an object at runtime are usually implemented.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't use a variable as name of an object. If I understood your use case correctly, you want `number_of_term` objects of type `term`. You can use a container class like `vector` to hold `number_of_term` objects. Something like this:

```
#include <vector>

struct Term
{
};

int main ()
{
  std::vector< Term > terms;
  int number_of_term = 10;

  for(int i = 0; i < number_of_term; ++i)
  {
    terms.push_back( Term() );
  }
}
```